# Django - Trying to call a model function from list_display in ModelAdmin

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, mozilla

I'm following along with Mozilla's Django tutorial, currently on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Admin_site) page.

I am trying to get the `ModelAdmin` for the `Book` model to call a function of the `Book` model in the `list_display` of the `ModelAdmin`.  This is to provide a list of genres in the list display.

I have the following code in the `admin.py` file:

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display('title', 'author', 'display_genre')
```

And in the `models.py` file:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    # ...
    def display_genre(self):
        return ', '.join(genre.name for genre in self.genre.all()[:3])
    display_genre.short_description = 'Genre'
```

I believe this was exactly what the tutorial asked me to add to each of these files.

Here's is what django tells me when I try to call `python manage.py makemigrations`:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'catalog.admin.BookAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[2]' refers to 'display_genre', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'BookAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'catalog.Book'.
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this - I have got it working. Here's how:

1. Comment out the `list_display` line in `admin.py`
2. Run `makemigrations` and `migrate`
3. Uncomment the `list_display` line in `admin.py`
4. Run `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Not getting the error now.

Perhaps the problem was that django was looking at the `admin.py` file before the database had been updated based on `models.py`, thus the `display_genre` function did not exist yet?

Comment: Since this is the answer to the question, you should mark with the tick mark to signify that. Other than that, sounds logical that when `makemigrations` is called, `admin.py` is called before `models.py`, thus it throws the error.

Comment: Says I have to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer